# Does the bios regulate temperature based on what cpu is installed?

Tags: cpu, bios, fan, temperature

I recently upgraded from an e8400 (intel dual 3.0) to a q9650 (quad 3.0). The original e8400 temperature at max load was 57 celcius. With the quad core it is now 71 C. I flashed a newer bios on and this still persists. I realize that 71 C is not in the danger zone but was wondering if the bios based the fan speeds off what cpu was installed and was thinking that it didnt recognize the new cpu. If i turned off thermal monitoring (in bios) and let the fan reach its max speed (very loud), the temps stayed relatively low.

Do the core 2 quads just run hotter than the core 2 duos or is there an issue with my bios?

Answer (score 0):

Quad core CPU will run hotter than Dual Core.

Have a look on Intel Ark here:
E8400 - http://ark.intel.com/products/33910 Max TDP - 65W
Q9650 - http://ark.intel.com/products/35428 Max TDP - 95W

So yes in general they will need more power, and the more power required, the more heat generated.

Also since you said you are upgrading the CPU, you may need to check a few more things:

- Do you need a bigger heatsink / new fan for the CPU to compensate for the additional heat?
- Did you / whoever done the installation, put enough thermal paste - correctly - to ensure the heat dissipate from the CPU into the heatsink?

Hope this helps.

Comment: The computer is an optiplex 960 which has multiple tiers for cpu: midrange : e8400 (which i had) and high: q9650 (what i have now). I dont think the cpu heatsink varies across models. Also thermal paste was applied properly (I applied the e8400 once and the temps were fine)

Comment: dell's heatsinks tend to be rather crappy compared to even the stock intel ones. I really think getting your hands on a aftermarket heatsink wold be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Quad core will be producing more heat than a dual core processor. Temperature varies with various processor and the temperature sensing on a mother board is done with sensors. There are situations when they fail to sense correctly and CPU fan over run. Also as you know the speed of fan is directly proportional to the heat produced. Try [hardware monitor](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html)  software for a detailed measure of your CPU temperature.